# How can I advance the offset of a Snowflake stream without a DML?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake streams are really cool, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply them to my use case. I have an external process that I want to use to detect changes to rows in my tables and notify other consumers that this happened. There are several ways to do this, but the nice thing about streams is that they can keep track of last time they were asked, and that would provide a clean way to track the offset and prevent dupes or gaps. For example, an alternative that uses explicit time travel would need externally keep track of the last time it ran the query, including accounting for clock skew between Snowflake and the process.

However, the offset only seems to move up if you push the data in it to another table. Meaning, this changes the offset:

```sql
insert into other_table select * from my_stream
```

but this does not:

```sql
select * from my_stream
```

In my case, I don't need the data in another table. I could insert into a temp table or something to create the *side effect* of advancing the offset, but that seems wasteful and messy. Is there some alternative I'm missing? Some way to "bump" the stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a where clause that selects no rows. It will still consume the stream.

```
insert into other_table select * from my_stream where false;
```

If you're never going to use the rows in the stream, just use it to detect when changes are there since the last consumption point, you may also consider replacing the stream.

```
create or replace stream my_stream on table my_table;
```

That will allow you to check for changes on the old stream and start with a new one when you do whatever needs to happen when the old one reports changed rows.

Comment: I have similar problem, I need to get latest rows from stream and advance the offsets. If I do 'select' and then 'insert' there could be a scenario when new rows are added between select and insert that I will lose.

Comment: If you do `insert into T1 select from MY_STREAM` any new rows arriving while the insert is happening should be after the offset advance. The stream should advance to the point when the DML transaction started, not when it ended.

Comment: first query is : `select * from my_stream` to get new rows.
second query: `insert into other_table select * from my_stream where false;`
to commit the stream. between first and second query, new rows might be added to the source table (stream.)

Comment: Just do it in one transaction - `insert into OTHER_TABLE select * form MY_STREAM`

Comment: but insert command won;t return the result set... i need to return to user the rows